# Website that allows user subdomains - what subdomains should I block people from using?

Tags: subdomain

My website is going to allow users to choose their own subdomain. I've got quite a list going but want to see if there are any others out there that you think would be worth it...

Thanks in advance!

```
$banned_subdomains = array(
    'cname',
    'www',
    'test',
    'js',
    'css',
    'cache',
    'static',
    'img',
    'images',
    'mail',
    'ftp',
    'cpanel',
    'whm',
    'webmail',
    'webdisk',
    'ns',
    'ns1',
    'ns2',
    'ns3',
    'ns4',
    'ns5',
    'register',
    'pop',
    'pop3',
    'beta',
    'stage',
    'dev',
    'http',
    'https',
    'abuse',
    'admin',
    'donate',
    'store',
    'payment',
    'smtp'
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

f--k, s--t,
xxx, adult, pr0n,
rss, soap, xml, html, xhtml,
bank, org, gov, microsoft,
cnarne, rnail, irng, irnages, srntp, webrnail, htrnl, xhtrnl, rnicrosoft

Comment: @bitbonk: What do you mean? I already listed microsoft.

Comment: @bitbonk: No, I didn't. Look closer. You have just demonstrated the reason for my last nine suggestions. You can also check out: http://www.rnicrosoft.com/

Answer (score 2):

I have a list going, too. Thinking about throwing it up on github.

Here it is so far, including what the OP and other comment have mentioned.

```
about
abuse
acme
ad
admanager
admin
ads
adsense
adult
adwords
affiliate
affiliatepage
affiliates
afp
analytics
android
answer
answers
ap
api
apis
app
appengine
appnews
apps
asdf
bank
base
beginners
beta
binaries
binary
blackberry
blog
blogs
blogsearch
book
books
buy
buzz
cache
calendar
cart
catalog
catalogs
chart
charts
chat
checkout
client
clients
clients1
cnarne
code
community
confirm
confirmation
contact-us
contacts
contactus
content
core
corp
countries
country
cpanel
css
dashboard
data
desktop
dev
developer
developers
dir
directory
dl
docs
documents
donate
download
downloads
e
earth
email
enable
encrypted
engine
error
errorlog
errors
features
feed
feedburner
feedproxy
feeds
file
files
finance
folder
folders
forum
forums
friend
friends
ftp
fuck
fun
fusion
gadget
gears
geographic
gettingstarted
gmail
go
goto
gov
graph
graphs
group
groups
help
home
html
htrnl
http
https
image
images
img
investor
investors
invoice
invoices
ios
ipad
iphone
irnages
irng
items
js
lab
labs
legal
list
lists
local
locale
location
log
logs
m
mail
manage
manager
map
maps
media
message
messages
misc
mms
mobile
model
models
money
movie
movies
my
net
network
networks
new
news
ns
ns1
ns2
ns3
ns4
ns5
org
other
p0rn
pack
page
pages
partner
partnerpage
partners
payment
people
person
places
podcasts
pop
pop3
popular
porn
pr0n
pricing
print
private
prod
production
profile
profiles
promo
promotions
proxies
proxy
public
purchase
queries
radio
random
reader
redirect
register
registration
release
reports
research
resolve
resolver
rnail
rnicrosoft
rss
sale
sandbox
scholar
search
seminars
server
servers
service
services
shop
shopping
shortcut
shortcuts
signin
signup
sitemap
sitenews
sites
sketchup
sky
slash
slashinvoice
slut
sms
smtp
soap
software
sorry
spreadsheet
spreadsheets
srntp
ssl
stage
staging
static
statistics
stats
store
suggest
suggestqueries
support
survey
surveys
surveytool
sync
sysadmins
talk
talkgadget
test
testing
text
tool
toolbar
toolbars
tools
trac
translate
translation
translator
trends
txt
ul
upload
uploads
validation
validations
video
video-stats
videos
voice
w
wave
webdisk
webmail
webmaster
webrnail
whm
whois
wifi
wiki
ww
www
wwww
xhtml
xhtrnl
xml
xxx
```

Comment: I finally made that github repo: https://github.com/ckrailo/Banned-Subdomains